# C# MVC EditorFor does not show passed value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, datepicker

I thought that this would be easy, but I have got problems showing the passed value in the editor box.

I pass some default `DateTime` in a Model to a View and I want to use `EditorFor`, because it is have nice calendar picker instead of simple `TextBoxFor`.

My `ReportQuery.cs`:

```
    public class ReportQuery
    {
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Since")]
        [BindRequired]
        public DateTime? Since { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "To")]
        [BindRequired]
        public DateTime? To { get; set; }
    }
```

My `RaportQuery.cshtml` - is a partial view

```
@model Castle.Feedback.Service.Models.ArticleViewer.ReportQuery

<form class="form-inline" asp-controller="ArticleViewer" asp-action="ReportExport" method="GET">
    <table class="edit-table">
        <tr>
            <th><span>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Since, new { @Value = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddMonths(-1) })</span></th>
            <th><span>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.To, new { @Value = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1) })</span></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">Generate</button>
</form>
```

But as you can see, default value is in `TextBoxFor`, but not in nice `EditorFor`. Do you have any idea how can I show the passed value in `EditorFor`?

[image: image description here]

Comment: This typically means that the date value attempted doesn't match the format your browser expected. Chrome, for instance, defaults to an [ISO-8601 date](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Not sure how the culture settings of your page or your instance of whatever browser you're using affects that.

Comment: Do you have a `DateTime.cshtml` view somewhere? If so, can you include that in your question?

Comment: I added my view in main question. It even does not work when I am using "Value" in view.

Comment: `Html.EditorFor` is going to try to load a view from `EditorTemplates` (either in `Views/Shared` or a folder with that name in the current controller's folder) that matches the name of the type of the field you're binding. So, do you have a `DateTime.cshtml` somewhere? If so, it would be helpful to see if you're applying any custom formatting.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd suggest seeing what `@Html.TextFor(model => model.Since, "{0:d}", new { @type = "date" })` does (`{0:d}` being the default date format for your culture settings).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did get it - I do not have DateTime.cshtml in my project.
I added RepoertQuery.cs also. I am using DataFormatString = "{0:g}"

Comment: Yeah, that `"{0:g}"` is going to cause issues with displaying in the browser. If you want it to work regardless of the user's language / culture setting, probably want `"{0:s}"`, which is the ISO-8601 format I mentioned earlier (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier)

Comment: Great! Thank you, it is working now. Can you write it as a answer? I will mark this as proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, most / all browsers which actually implement a date-picker control (or support the `<input type="date" />` input in any fashion) require the input's value to be in the only "universal" pattern, defined by ISO-8601.

.NET has a [standard format identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier) you can use to apply this format, `s`, like so:

```
@Html.TextFor(model => model.Since, "{0:s}", new { @type = "date" })
```

If you only want the date part of the value, you can use a custom format for an ISO-8601 short date:

```
@Html.TextFor(model => model.Since, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type = "date" })
```

If you use this format, your DateTime value will have 00:00:00 as the time part of the value when posting to the controller.